# python realtime plot in Tkinter window

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I want to plot sensor date in a time-based plot which shall be embedded in a Tkinter window. For the moment I only want to plot y1List vs. xList.

Up to now I didn't find a solution on stackoverflow to my specific use case.

My code:

```
import datetime                 # für Datum/Uhrzeit
from tkinter import *           # für GUI
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.backends.tkagg as tkagg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_tkagg import FigureCanvasTkAgg
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


#Animation function
def animate(ax,xList,y1List,y2List):
    time = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%H:%M:%S")
    lb_Time.config(text=time)
    lb_Time['text'] = time
    xList.append(time)
#   Replace sample data below my real data...
    y1List.append(np.sin(len(xList)))
    y2List.append(2*np.sin(len(xList)))
    # Limit x and y lists to 20 items
    xList = xList[-20:]
    y1List = y1List[-20:]
    y2List = y2List[-20:]
    line, = ax.plot_date(mpl.dates.datestr2num(xList), y1List)
    plt.show()
    fenster.after(1000,animate,ax,xList,y1List,y2List)


fenster = Tk()
fenster.title("Monitoring")
fenster.geometry("450x400")
lb_Time = Label(fenster)
exit_button = Button(fenster, text="Beenden", command=fenster.destroy, fg="red")    
lb_Time.grid(row=2, column=0,pady=20)

xList = []
y1List =[]
y2List = []

fig = plt.Figure(figsize=(2, 2))
canvas = FigureCanvasTkAgg(fig, master=fenster)
canvas.get_tk_widget().grid(row=3,column=1,pady=20)

ax = fig.add_subplot(111)
line, = ax.plot_date(xList, y1List)
animate(ax,xList,y1List,y2List)

fenster.mainloop()
```

My problem is that the plot is only static and plotting only 1 point at an y value of 34. Why is not updating every 1sec and why is it 34 at all (as I used sinus...) ?

Answer (score 0):

I've done that using this code

```
...

from matplotlib.animation import FuncAnimation

...

_ANIM_INTERVAL = 1000  # Milliseconds.


def animate(counter: int) -> None:
    """Refresh graph.

    :param counter: Function call counter (2 times for 0!!!).
    """
    ...

...

_ = FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=_ANIM_INTERVAL)
show(fig)
```

JM

Answer (score 0):

mainloop is a blocking statement, i.e. when it encounters it, now further code will be run. You can verify this by putting a print statement after mainloop. I am not too familiar with tkinter inner-working but building animation function can be written pretty trivially with native matplotlib:

```
import numpy as np, matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
# dummy data
N      = 100
buffer = np.zeros((N, 2))
p = ax.plot(*buffer.T, marker = '.')[0] # get plot object
while True:
    for idx in range(N):
        buffer[idx, :] = np.random.rand(buffer.shape[1])
        p.set_data(*buffer.T)
        # recompute data limits
        ax.relim()
        ax.axes.autoscale_view(True, True, True)

        # update figure; flush events
        fig.canvas.draw()
        fig.canvas.flush_events()
```